# Unable to Launch a background app with voice commands in Cortana in UWP app?

Tags: uwp, cortana

currently im working on cortana integration in my UWP app using C# and xaml.
I have followed the below article to get started with cortana
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn630430.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396
i wrote all the code that needed, i can able to launch a foreground app using cortana and i can able to perform operations.
But i tried to launch a background app using Cortana, the app is opening till splash screen and then the app crashes.
i followed the below article for background app launching using Cortana
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn974228.aspx
I followed the cortana voice command sample provided by Microsoft and i have followed the above link, still im unable to make it.
Is there any other cool article to fix this issue and how to debug the app when we are launching background app so that i can keep a breakpoint in the code and i can able to figure out the issue.
Anybody please help me out on this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

You can debug a background task in Cortana by setting visual studio to wait for your code to start. It will detect Cortana loading your background task, and attach automatically:

The steps vary depending on the project type (C#, js or c++/cx), but the general steps to debug it is

1. Open the project properties for your startup project (right click on the project -> properties)
2. Go to the Debug (or debugging) section of the project's properties
3. Set either one of "Launch Application" to 'No' (js or c++ apps), or "Do not start, but wait for my code to start" to be checked (c# apps)
4. Start debugging.

Your code will deploy, but VS will wait. Then trigger your Cortana background task, and it will automatically attach to BackgroundTaskHost.exe when your code triggers.

If you find that VS never attaches and you can't hit breakpoints, you need to investigate if you've missed a step somewhere:

- Check to make sure the VCD you're installing has a proper entry for the VoiceCommandService tag. The target should match the name of the entrypoint set in the package manifest. Spelling and case matters.
- Check the package manifest to ensure that the entrypoint is the correct full namespace
- Check that your background task is actually being included in the deployed output of the build. Add a reference from your main app's startup project to the background task (Open the References section of the startup project, right click, add a reference, and reference the background task's project). This will cause VS to copy the project to the output so that Cortana can find it and run it.

If it's failing at some point after the breakpoint hits, you can follow up with where specifically it's failing and I can probably make some suggestions, if it's not hitting an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Voice Command wont fire "OnLaunched" Event in App.xaml.cs.

But u can check OnActivated if the Arguments of Type VoiceCommandActivatedEventArgs

```
protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        base.OnActivated(args);

        if (args.Kind == ActivationKind.VoiceCommand)
        {
            // Run your OnLunched Stuff
        }
    }
```